# Submitting a paper, and presenting it at a conference - conflicts?

Tags: journals, ethics, conference, etiquette, paper-submission

So, sorry if this is a daft question...

I've recently completed a paper that I'm hoping to submit to a journal later this week.

I think we have something important to say, and I want to disseminate the results more widely, in particular there's a conference I have my eye on. Their deadline is also at the end of this week.

Is it acceptable to submit the same paper to both journal and conference? Or will I get into trouble in the same way that I would if I submitted to two journals at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally one submits to a conference and its associated journal at the same time. May be different in different fields though... mine was engineering...

Comment: yes - it's tricky. The journal and conference are two separate entities - I'm hoping to publish in the journal, because they published the paper I'm critiquing, but there aren't all that may conferences in my field - so they aren't all that closely linked

Comment: Then if they are two separate entities you may need two completely separate papers.... As most journals / conferences have a question like "has this material been submitted elsewhere"....

Comment: This really depends on the field. Some fields publish only in journals and conferences are for work in progress (including papers submitted for publication); in other fields, conferences are chiefly publication venues. In the first, your only problem will be to saveguard the blindness of peer-review. In the second, I don't know.

Comment: Fyi this is a perfectly relevant question imho.

Comment: I don’t have time to write an answer, but in my field this would be perfectly acceptable. This is because conferences are for works in progress (@henning case 1) and all conference proceedings are negligible enough that they are not considered publication by our journals. What is the nature of your field’s conferences?

Comment: @SolarMike That's a totally new idea to me - in my field, conferences don't have associated journals.

Comment: @AzorAhai well, the conference I presented at had an associated book with it 1500 pages or more at least 6cm thick....

Comment: @Solar Full of abstracts or entire articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in the same situation, written a paper, and wanted to disseminate the findings to a wider audience and hence, presented the work at a conference. I am in applied environmental science, and I feel that this is relatively common in my field.

My approach to this situation, bearing in mind there was to be published conference proceedings was to focus on a very specific element of the new methodological development that I worked on, and presented this at the conference, under a similar - but 'different enough' title than the paper. This parallel journal/conference writing also has to be used to be able to honestly answer the journal question, 'is this work being submitted elsewhere?'. Clearly you need to be able to answer no - its not.

This approach allowed me to go into some very fine detail of the new methods that was of interest to the specialist audience at the conference, that otherwise was far too detailed for the journal readership.

At the end of the conference presentation, I also signposted to the paper that was under review and the journal it was with, and some folk said post-conference that they would look for the journal paper when published.

So, in short, I would say that there has to be differences between the two submissions, but there is no problem in having them linked by common ground and to highlight an upcoming journal paper.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to depend on the field. But, in most fields, I think that you risk being rejected by both the journal and the conference. Journals, especially, want to publish what is new and ask you to assure them that you haven't submitted elsewhere.

If you happen to "sneak it through" in one instance, don't expect a happy reception in the future.

Again, in some fields, conferences are the main venue for presenting new work. Conferences in CS, for example, also publish proceedings in which the accepted papers are printed as a matter of course.

That said, an abstract of a paper submitted to a journal might be acceptable at an unrelated conference. Likewise a follow-on result to something submitted to one is probably acceptable to the other.

But the best way to be sure is to ask. Both the journal editor and the conference chair will give you the best and only valid advice. Both the journal and conference submission procedures probably already make it pretty clear what is allowed and what is not. If either objects to a double submission, then you should tread carefully.

Comment: Thanks, definitely don't want to piss anybody off (any more than strictly necessary) so I'll do a bit of digging.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of editorial policy: both the journal and the conference certainly have a policy in place about such cases. If their policy is not clear from their website, you can send an email to the editor asking about it.

In my experience (computer science), it is common for a conference/journal to allow authors to "submit elsewhere" , but be careful: this often implies that you would have to withdraw one of them in case you are accepted to both. Another option is simply to submit different content: usually conference papers are shorter, so in the journal one you can afford to study a particular aspect of the topic in more detail, thus making it a significantly different contribution.